# Launching multiple bash scripts as separate jobs

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have this:

```
 cat jobpaths.txt | while read LINE; do
     cd $LINE
     ./run_scrape.sh
     cd ..
     cd ..
     cd ..
     setsid
 done
```

It is supposed to read a 3-level subdirectory from jobpaths.txt (e.g. /foo/bar/foobar. Then cd into that directory and launch a script. A script of this same name exists in all subdirs listed in jobpaths.txt.

The `cd ..` times 3 is supposed to go back to the initial dir.

`setsid` is supposed to launch a new cpu thread before doing the same throughout all dirs in the txt.

However it just launches the first job.

Comment: If your `jobpaths.txt` is not guaranteed to not have spaces in directory names, then `$LINE` needs to handle this, e.g.: "$LINE".  GNU Parallel https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ is a good tool for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Is this an actual code? `setsid` does not make any sense without further parameters!

Comment: Using `cd` this way is unsafe -- if anything weird happens (error `cd`ing, entry in file isn't exactly 3 levels, etc) the script will run off the rails and start executing in unexpected locations. Use `pushd`/`popd` to return to the original directory after a change, and add error checks in case any change fails! As for the original problem, it's hard to say for sure without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but the run_scrape.sh script might be reading from stdin and hence bogarting the rest of the dir list.

Comment: BTW, `cat jobpaths.txt | while ...` is a [useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat), which has the unfortunate side effect of forcing the `while` loop to run in a subshell. Use `while ... done <jobpaths.txt` instead.

Comment: I think your understanding of `setsid` is wrong: `setsid` is about being a process group leader. I think you are simply wanting another process started.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
cat jobpaths.txt | parallel 'cd {} && ./run_scrape.sh'
```

It will run one job for each core until all jobs are done.

Comment: It depends on where the `run_scrape.sh` script is located.  If each directory has its own copy (or version), then what you've got is fine.  If not, you probably need to capture the current working directory and prefix the command with that, which also leads to using double quotes rather than single quotes around the command that is run by `parallel`.  Does `parallel` wait for all its children to die (at least with an option if not by default)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Given OP's code it looks as if he has `run_scrape.sh` in each dir. `parallel` waits for children to die and returns 0 if all children returned 0 and non-zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Using `parallel` as suggested elsewhere is probably good, but you can adapt your code so it works.

```
cwd="$PWD"
cat jobpaths.txt |
while read LINE; do
     (cd "$LINE" && "$cwd/run_scrape.sh" &)
done
```

The `(cd "$LINE" && "$cwd/run_scrape.sh" &)` construct runs a sub-shell which changes directory and runs the `run_scrape.sh` script from the starting directory.  If you really have a (different?) `run_scrape.sh` script in each sub-directory, then you can avoid the `cwd` variable and continue to use `./run_scrape.sh` command.  The big advantage of this is that you don't have to worry about changing back; the shell running the loop never changes directory.

Note, however, that Bash will run that pipeline in sub-shells, and there's a secondary sub-shell because of the `(…)` notation.  This means that the scraper jobs are all separate from the main shell.  You have to work hard to keep track of them all.  You'd probably place the `&` after the `(…)` notation so that the sub-shell as a whole is run in background; the shell running the `while` loop can then wait for all the children.  However, the main shell would still not own the children.  You can use `shopt -s lastpipe` so that the `while` loop is run by the main shell, or you can use:

```
cwd="$PWD"
while read LINE; do
     (cd "$LINE" && "$cwd/run_scrape.sh") &
done < <(cat jobpaths.txt)
```

so that the `while` loop is run in the main shell and it can wait for all its children.  You might want to capture the PIDs of the child processes by stashing `$!` values in an array in the loop. Or you might simply put a `wait` after the `while` loop to wait for all the children to exit.

Comment: While this solution may work in this particular case it is a solution that does not scale: If `jobpaths.txt` contains more than 100000 entries, most machines will keel over. Even 1000 entries can overload small machines.